# Top growth of new apple tree is snapped

Tags: apples

We just got some new apple trees and the top section arrived damaged. Because it’s the very top, will this affect the future growth, and how to mend the situation? [image]

Answer (score 6):

Cut, cleanly (sharp shears, don't tear the bark) at an angle just above (but don't damage it by trying to get too close) the first bud below the break.

[image]

This will have little to no effect on the future - it's quite common to prune trees shorter when planting, since the roots are reduced and damaged inevitably by transplanting, so supporting less top growth is more balanced until they recover.

An alternate choice would be to cut back to the first actual branch below the break. That already has a "terminal bud" and will be ready to take over as the leader a bit faster than the clump of leaves that will have to decide to grow a shoot in order to take over that job.

Comment: Already gave a thumbs up. You would decide on which choice of place to cut based on the tree overall shape. The end goal is an umbrella shape so that when the tree has a heavy load of fruit the branches don't wind up snapping. Though, at this early stage, it may be difficult to discern how that will work out.